# Postfix main.cf broken

Tags: linux, ubuntu, postfix

I have the following **main.cf**: http://pastebin.com/m55f6a90 and I am not able to telnet from another machine to the one on which this Postfix is installed. In /var/log/mail.info I get the following errors/warnings:

```
Aug 27 19:38:57 realshit postfix/smtpd[3960]: initializing the server-side TLS engine
Aug 27 19:38:57 realshit postfix/smtpd[3960]: warning: unknown SASL security options value "noanonymus" in "noanonymus"
Aug 27 19:38:57 realshit postfix/smtpd[3960]: warning: bad per-session SASL security properties
Aug 27 19:38:57 realshit postfix/smtpd[3960]: fatal: SASL per-connection initialization failed
Aug 27 19:38:58 realshit postfix/master[3285]: warning: process /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd pid 3960 exit status 1
Aug 27 19:38:58 realshit postfix/master[3285]: warning: /usr/lib/postfix/smtpd: bad command startup -- throttling
```

I assume it has something to do with a typo, but I am a beginner and it's hard to tell.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typo on line 47

```
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymus
```

Should be:

```
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
```

You were missing an 'o'.